# Singleton Class not updating properly

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, singleton

I've got a collectionViewController and a normal viewcontroller. When a cell is tapped it goes to the VC and sets the label to the cell tapped. The variable for this is in a singleton class.

The issue I'm having is that the first time you tap a cell and go to the VC the label doesn't say anything (console prints correct data though). Then you go back to the collectionView and tap a different cell, the label in the view now shows the **cell you tapped previously**.

I tried cleaning the build folder etc. but didn't do anything. I also tried another method - `let CVC = CollectionViewController()` then `lbl.text = CVC.cellTapped` (create var first) but that didnt work either.

**SharingManager.swift**

```
class SharingManager { 
          var cellChoose = String()
static let sharedInstance = SharingManager()
}
```

**CollectionViewController.swift**

```
    class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    let sm = SharingManager.sharedInstance 


  override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell
    let lbl = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    lbl.text = String(indexPath.row)

    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    sm.cellChoose = "cell\(indexPath.row)"
   print(sm.cellChoose)

}

}
```

**VC2.swift** *(the viewcontroller tapping a cell takes you to)*

```
class VC2: UIViewController {


    let sm2 = SharingManager.sharedInstance

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl2: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.lbl2.text = sm2.cellChoose
        //print(sm2.cellChoose)


    }
```

Comment: How do you go to the 2nd view controller? And did you try putting breakpoints on the two lines that read and write the `cellChoose` property and see what order they are being called?

Comment: I think this not a good use case for a singleton. If you want to pass data from the CollectionView to a another viewcontroller, you would be better off using the `prepareForSegue` method to set a property on the VC.

Comment: It's unclear how you're navigating to VC2, but Chances are moving `lbl2.text = sm2.cellChoose` to `viewWillAppear` will fix your issue.

Comment: I just created a segue on the storyboard to go to VC2 @rmaddy

Comment: I just created a segue on the storyboard to go to VC2 @TheAppMentor

Comment: Thanks, it tried that and it works fine now. can you post that as answer so i can accept it (see comment for navigation method) @PEEJWEEJ

Comment: Issue that may be linked with previous comment (not tested, but I've seen this behavior that it wasn't calling `prepareForSegue()` at time): I guess that you did connect the segue from the cell to the second viewcontroller. So it may call your second viewcontroller (and then the `viewDidLoad()`) before `didSelectItem` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're navigating via a segue, it's possible your new `ViewController` is loaded before `didSelectItem` is called. Moving `lbl2.text = sm2.cellChoose` to `viewWillAppear` will fix your issue.

The "correct" way to do this with segues is handle this in `prepareForSegue`, but what you have now will work.

Comment: When I tried this in a blank project it worked fine but when I added it to my project it doesn't work anymore. How do I set the variable in prepareForSegue as it's out of the didSelectItemAt... method

Comment: Use https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618099-indexpathsforselecteditems in prepareforsegue to get the selected index path(s)